# Visual C# How do you simulate click a button?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to run a button's event handler from code?

I tried

`btn.click();
 btn.mousedown();`

I tried calling the event handler but I didn't know what parameter goes to `RoutedEventArgs e`

Comment: Does `btn.performClick()` do anything for you?

Comment: try new RoutedEventArgs ()

Comment: you need to provide more tags to be specific- WPF/Winforms.

Comment: @Nikita not if he do what I suggested

Comment: @CollinD I would rather send the args as null in this case since nothing is coming from the button, it is unlikely that he uses args inside the event handler.

Comment: @AFJ  Instead asking how on air,  post your code and show where you stuck.

Comment: Instead of trying to invoke a event, just have your event be one line of code that calls a separate function, then when you need to manually invoke it you just call the separate function instead of the event.

Comment: @bto.rdz yep, that worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can directly call the button using `btn.click();` and `btn.mousedown();` and pass a `new EventArgs(`) RoutedEventArgs.

Like

```
btn.click(btn,new EventArgs());
```

You can also call

```
btn.PerformClick();
```

Comment: if such a case occur, i would rather suggest extracting separate method with common code and invoke where necessary.